# Any way to get non-overriden spark config from command

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am running the following spark command

> spark-submit --name Basic_class1 --class com.test2.Basic
>   /Users/myusername/Downloads/project/spark/target/target-basic.jar

In the main file,

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Basic")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
```

Here, the sparkSession overrides the appname that's provided in the command and sets it to "Basic" from "Basic_class1". However, there is a requirement where I need the non-overriden parameter "Basic_class1" in my dependecy file, but I don't have access to the main file where they set the appname. Is there anyway to get that parameter after the appname is overriden?

I know I can set some property in the properties file for this, but that would require a lot of changes in some other portion. So, that's why I was wondering if we can do it in the code itself.

**Approaches I tried**

I have looked on the parameters returned by `sparkContext.conf().getAll()`, but the appname is overriden there as well. I have been looking into the other methods in spark context and config as well, but not able to get any results. Also, didn't get any help from internet either.

**Edit 1**

For the spark submit command and sparksession as mentioned in question, if we do

> System.out.println(sparkSession.sparkContext().appName());

then it prints "Basic". However, if we change the sparksession creation to

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
                .builder()
//                .appName("Basic")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
```

then the

> System.out.println(sparkSession.sparkContext().appName());

would print out "Basic_class1". So, if I don't give the appName in my code, whatever is there in --name is printed. But since appName is there in the file, I was wondering if I can still get the --name?

Comment: `--name` is for Yarn resource manager to display and is the name of the application. SparkSession app name is the name of the session, different concepts. Could I also ask what is a dependency file?

Comment: @SašaZejnilović I have clarified my question more in the edit. Hope it helps. By dependency file, I meant my file was a utility file, containing common functions for modules to use.